# Angular2, testing and resolved data: How to test ngOnInit?

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-runner, resolver

I'm working through the [Angular2 testing guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html) and wish to write a test for the `ngOnInit()` function. The one from the [Routing section of the programming guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing#routing-component) has this format:

```
let org: Org = null;

ngOnInit(): void {
  let that = this;

  this.route.data
    .subscribe((data: { org: Org }) => {
      that.org = data.org;
    });
}
```

This is fulfilled through a resolver, like:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Org> {
  let id = this.authService.user.orgId;

  return this.orgService
    .getOrg(id)
    .map(
      (org: Org) : Org => {

        if(org) {
          return org;
        } else { 
          // If  the Org isn't available then the edit page isn't appropriate.
          this.router.navigate(['/provider/home']);
          return null;
        }
     })
    .first();
}
```

The code works OK, but I'm not sure how to write a test for `ngOnInit`.  The examples available to me assume that an embedded `OrgService` can be replaced by a `MockOrgService`.  However, all I have is a resolver.

I'll eventually figure out how to test the resolver on its own.  Are there any useful tests I can do with a resolver-based `ngOnInit`?

Comment: I think testing ngOnInit should be the Angular team's responsibility, you should just need to test the methods that you are calling from it

Comment: Hi. How did you unit test the Resolve class on its own? I'm looking to do that, just wondering what your solution was

Answer (score 44, accepted):

What is the behavior or the `ngOnInit` method? All it does is assign the value of the `org` when the route data is resolved. So that's all you really need to test.

```
let routeStub;

beforeEach(() => {
  routeStub = {
    data: null
  }

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: routeStub }  
    ]
  })
})

it('should assign org when route is resolved', async(() => {
  let org = new Org()
  routeStub.data = Observable.of(org)

  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(component.org).toEqual(org)
  })
}))
```

Comment: Hot stuff!  That is the third time you've saved me, because you also answered another Q without knowing it.  That is:  How do I get rid of the "No provider for Activated Route!" error.  Thanks, Jerome.

Comment: async() (2nd parameter of it() ) should be used if the test body makes an XHR call, otherwise use fakeAsync: https://angular.io/guide/testing#async-test-with-async

Comment: fixture.whenStable() saved my day!

Comment: Would you be able to assist with an issue I'm having with a unit test failing as a result of using route params in ngOnInit().  Here is the stack link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64345423/how-would-i-mock-route-queryparams-in-ngoninit-in-a-spec-test

Comment: @Paul, would you be able to assist with a similar issue I'm having?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64345423/how-would-i-mock-route-queryparams-in-ngoninit-in-a-spec-test

Comment: Can you please answer my question also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70907350/how-to-write-unit-test-for-ngoninit-with-jasmine-karma/70907621#70907621

Answer (score 25):

I was trying to test ngOnInit() for a component, and unfortunately the accepted answer didn't work for me. However, this did:

```
describe('your test', () => {
  beforeEach(async() => {
    // set up your component as necessary

    component.ngOnInit();

    await fixture.whenStable();
  });

  it('should verify your test', () => {
    // run your expectation
  });
});
```

Comment: generally we do TestBed.createComponent(...) to get the component which I suppose calls ngOnInit. Wouldn't we end up calling ngOnInit twice?

Comment: Calling "component.ngOnInit()" is not necessary unless your unit test creates a new object outside of the "beforeEach" function call.

Comment: @Ken That is not the behavior I am seeing on my project. I can verify this by attaching a spy to ngOnInit and then await a stable fixture.