# How would I mock route queryParams in ngOnInit() in a spec test

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router, angular2-testing

Failed: Cannot read property 'queryParams' of null
at

I'm assuming it's because I have the following in ngOnInit():

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(async params => {
      this.userInfo = await JSON.parse(params['user_info']);
    });
```

So far I've tried constructing my unit test with the following:

```
describe('AddItineraryPage', () => {
  let component: AddItineraryPage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AddItineraryPage>;
  let routeStub;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    routeStub = null;

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AddItineraryPage ],
      imports: [IonicModule.forRoot(), FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [
        {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: routeStub}
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddItineraryPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    routeStub.queryParams = {
    displayName: '',
    dateOfBirth: '',
    email: '',
    photos: [],
    location: '',
    bio: '',
    intDestination: [],
    userId: ''};

    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.parse?` Aren't `queryParams`' values supposed to be (simple) strings?

Comment: @AndreiGătej I'm passing an object as a queryParams and you have to use JSON.stringify to pass an object.  So once I'm in the page I have to then parse to make it an object again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cannot read property 'queryParams' of null

So when the property `queryParams` is being called on the `routeStub` object, it is null. You initialized the `routeStub` to null, so it makes sense. `ngOnInit()` gets called the first time you call `fixture.detectChanges()`, so you need to assign something to the `routeStub` *before* you make that call.

Also in your code, you call `subscribe()` on the `queryParams`, so you will need to assign an Observable-like object to the property. You can just use an actual `Observable` by using `Observable.of()`.

So your test code should look more like

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
  routeStub = null;
  ...
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddItineraryPage);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  // remove fixture.detectChanges() as it calls ngOnInit()
}));

it('should create', () => {
  routeStub = {
    queryParams: of({
      user_info: '{
        "displayName": "UserName"
      }'
      // not sure why you are calling `JSON.parse()`
      // but if you are doing that, then user_info should
      // be a JSON string
    })
  };

  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(component.userInfo.displayName).toBe('UserName');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Paul.  I only have the following error now: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

I'm using JSON.Parse because I'm passing the IUser object to this page in a query param.  I have to Stringify this in order to pass the object and once I'm on the page I parse it back to an object.  Is there a better way to do this?  I'm using Firebase and trying to limit my calls to the backend.  
So all of the other errors are going except for the JSON error.  Any ideas on how to resolve this?  I updated my code snippet with your suggestion

Comment: The fixture.detectChanges() was an oversight...removed it and it's working now.  Thanks @Paul