# How to write unit test for ngOnInit with Jasmine/Karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Actually my question should be "What to test in ngOnInit". I've started writing unit test 2 days back for my company code. So I cant show you the entire exact code. I've a component:

**filter-tree.component.ts**

```
import { FilterPanelService } from 'src/app/core/services/filters/filter-panel.service';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class FilterTreeComponent implements OnInit {
    
    constructor(
        ...
        private filterPanelService: FilterPanelService
    ) {
        ...
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.filterPanelService.getEnableChildFilterNode$().subscribe(res => {
            this.isChildFilterNodeDisabled = res;
        });
    }
}
```

Test coverage is very less. I need to bump it up by covering `ngOnInit`.
Just see If I'm doing it correctly. Coverage report still says it is not covered.

**filter-tree.component.spec.ts**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
...
import { FilterPanelService } from '.../filter-panel.service';

describe('FilterTreeComponent', () => {
    let component: FilterTreeComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<FilterTreeComponent>;
    let mockFilterPanelService;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        mockFilterPanelService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getEnableChildFilterNode$']);
        mockFilterPanelService.getEnableChildFilterNode$.and.returnValue(of(false));

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [...],
            declarations: [FilterTreeComponent,...],
            providers: [
                ...
                { provide: FilterPanelService, useValue: mockFilterPanelService }
            ],
            schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FilterTreeComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should get response when the component loads', () => {
        mockFilterPanelService.getEnableChildFilterNode$.and.returnValue(of(false));
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.isChildFilterNodeDisabled).toBeFalsy();
    });
});
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

This is the best youtube playlist I've found, on how to create your unit tests:
[Advanced Web Apps 2019 | Unit Testing in Angular](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8jcXf-CLpxolmjV5_taFP0c5LyCveDF1)

Comment: Awesome. This is what i really needed.